# Relax a command within an environment

Tags: environments, lengths

A new environment is to be designed which prints some length. The environment is used multiple times in the document, hence the length is calculated more than once, leading to error "command #length# already defined". `let\command\relax` was tried, but no use. A MWE is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%This is the environment
\newenvironment{relaxation}{
\newlength\mytmplen
\setlength\mytmplen{10pt}
\the\mytmplen
\let\mytmplen\relax
}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{relaxation}
Runs fine, and pdf-output is also fine, when called once
\end{relaxation}

\begin{relaxation}
Shows error, but pdf-output is fine, when called again
\end{relaxation}

\end{document}
```

Note that, the pdf output is fine. The compiler (Texmaker) shows error, that's it. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: For completion, what I am trying to accomplish is added here. A new block is created, which has a title, a body, and a line separating the last two. The line width should be equal to the lengthier one, ie title/body. Therefor, line widths (of title, body, and the lengthier one) are calculated each time within the environment, and the block appears multiple times in the text. A full working example is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

%This is the full environment
\NewEnviron{relaxation}[1]{
\newlength\tw\settowidth\tw{\textbf{#1}}
\newlength\bw\settowidth\bw{\BODY}

%Picking and assigning the lengthier one
\ifdim \tw > \bw
 \newlength{\lw}\settowidth{\lw}{\hspace{\tw}}
\else
 \newlength{\lw}\settowidth{\lw}{\hspace{\bw}}
\fi

%Trying to un-define
\let\bw\relax
\let\tw\relax

\begin{minipage}{\lw}
\textbf{#1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[rounded corners=0.1ex, fill=red] (0, 0) rectangle (\lw, 0.2ex) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\let\lw\relax
%Trying to undefine

\BODY
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{relaxation}{Title}
Runs fine, and pdf-output is also fine, when called once
\end{relaxation}

\begin{relaxation}{Title}
Shows error, but pdf-output is fine, when called again
\end{relaxation}

\end{document}
```

As said earlier, the output is fine, but the compiler shows error.
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Easy fix: move the `\newlength` outside the environment definition,such that it is defined for the whole document. Or use a scratch dimension (`\@tempdima`, `\@tempdimb`, `\dimen@`). But again, an appropriate answer might depend on what you want to do.

Comment: Why would you allocate the temporary lenght each time?

Comment: Dear @campa, please have a look at edited question.

Comment: Dear @egreg, please have a look at the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you allocate those length registers each time?

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

%This is the full environment
\newlength\bw
\newlength\lw
\newlength\tw

\NewEnviron{relaxation}[1]{%
  \settowidth\tw{\textbf{#1}}%
  \settowidth\bw{\BODY}%
  %Picking and assigning the lengthier one
  \ifdim \tw > \bw
    \setlength{\lw}{\tw}%
  \else
    \setlength{\lw}{\bw}%
  \fi
  \begin{minipage}{\lw}
  \textbf{#1}\par
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[rounded corners=0.1ex, fill=red] (0, 0) rectangle (\lw, 0.2ex) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \BODY
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{relaxation}{Title}
Runs fine, and pdf-output is also fine, when called once
\end{relaxation}

\bigskip

\begin{relaxation}{Title}
Shows error, but pdf-output is fine, when called again
\end{relaxation}

\end{document}
```

No `\settowidth{\lw}{\hspace{\tw}}`, but `\setlength{\lw}{\tw}`.

Beware of unprotected end-of-lines that can become unwanted spaces in the output.

[image]